# HTTPResponse's string from Play is empty

Tags: java, android, playframework

I am using Play and Faye on my Server. Play is used for API calls, while Faye is used for communication with the clients.

So, I have this method in the **server**:

```
public static Result broadcast(String channel, String message)
{
   try
   {
       FayeClient faye = new FayeClient("localhost");
       int code = faye.send(channel, message);
       // print the code (prints 200).

       return ok("Hello"); <------------ This is what we care about.
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      return ok("false");
   }
}
```

this is the code on the **client**, which is an android phone.
(it's the HTTP post method, which sends something to the server and gets a response back
**The problem is, I can't print the message of the response.**

```
public static String post(String url, List<BasicNameValuePair> params)
{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String result = "";
    // Prepare a request object
    HttpPost httpPost;
    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try
    {
        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
            obj.put(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    // Add your data
    try
    {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
HttpResponse httpResponse;
        try
        {
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);


            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("RestClient", "result = \"" + str + "\""); // hello should be printed here??
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // ...
}
```

The problem is that in logcat, what is printed is [result = ""]. Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool such as Fiddler and see what the HTTP response contains.